# Cannot run 'pyside2-uic' on windows executable built with pyinstaller

Tags: pyqt, pyinstaller, pyside2

I am using the PySide2 python bindings for Qt.

Update: I have designed some .Ui files with Qt Designer and loading those during run-time, e.g:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtUiTools

UI_CLASS, _ = QtUiTools.loadUiType("win_main.ui")

class WinMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, UI_CLASS):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)  # This sets up layout and widgets that are defined
```

Version:

- Python 3.9.2 final (amd64)
- pyside2-5.15.2
- Windows 10 (Build 19042.844)

I have successfully built a Windows executable with pyinstaller 4.2.

PyInstaller-command:

```
pyinstaller .\src\main.py --name=MyApp --noconfirm --windowed --clean --onedir --log-level=ERROR --hidden-import=PySide2.QtXml --icon=.\img\MyApp.ico --add-data="LICENSE.txt;." --add-data="README.md;." --add-data="changelog.md;." --add-data="data;data" --add-data="img;img" --add-data="ui;ui"
```

The portable Windows-Executable "MyApp.exe" runs fine. But: if I move the dist folder (I want to make a portable windows-program out of my python program) to any remote PC, the exe exits with an error message on the remote PC.

```
Cannot run 'pyside2-uic'
...
Check if 'pyside2-uic' is in PATH
```

I tried almost everything to avoid this and I am running out of ideas.

What is missing on the remote PC?

Hint: I get the same result on *my PC*, when I rename the following folder for testing reasons:
%LOCALPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PySide2
But copying this folder to my dist folder and putting it into the PATH environment variable does not solve this.

Any help/suggestion appreciated!

Comment: I try to do it before using a ui file, but it did not work for me, but after converting the a file into py file, after that I used the `loadUiType` only for testing and developing and if I want to make an exe i convert the ui to py